# Root using symlink for .vim. Vim configuration of other user not inherited as expected!

Tags: vimrc

I have customized my Vim environment under my "login" ID ${HOME}. 
Everything is under **~login_ID/.vim** (*no customizations under ~login_ID/.gvim*).

I have created a symbolic link /root/.vim pointing to ~login_ID/.vim :

```
(~) # ln -s ~login_ID/.vim .vim
```

Why doesn't root ID inherit all ~login_ID/.vim content in usable fashion ???

IMAGE when viewed by root in vim (called from **MATE terminal** on **UbuntuMATE 20.04**) before the symlink is created: [image: This1]

IMAGE  when viewed by root in vim ... after the symlink is created: [image: This2]

IMAGE  when viewed by login_ID in vim (again called from MATE terminal), which is behaviour expected for root with symbolic link in place: [image: This3]

Comment: Oh, and welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: It's always seems to be the small stuff which will trip you up without realizing it!  I completely forgot about the ~root/.vimrc being non-existent.  With that in place, all is working as expected.  Also, thank you for pointing out the ~/.vim/vimrc approach.  Thats PERFECT!  Thank you very much, filbranden.

Comment: I would recommend not doing this and just using sudoedit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, beyond the `~/.vim` directory, there's the file `~/.vimrc` which is used for configuration.

So either you're missing the `~/.vimrc` from your login user, or you have a different `/root/.vimrc` in your root user that is being picked as the main vimrc file.

Note that (at least with recent versions of Vim 8.x, IIRC Vim 7.x didn't support this path) you can store your main user vimrc file at path `~/.vim/vimrc`, so that all of your configuration is contained inside the `~/.vim` path.

But, even in that case, make sure you don't have a `/root/.vimrc` in the home directory of the root user, in which case Vim might end up picking up that one instead of the one inside the `~/.vim` symlink.